# Typehint addition of lists in python mypy where the lists have different structures

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Example:

```
# check.py
x = [("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]
y = [("x", [("1", "2"), ("3", "4")])]
z = x + y
```

where `mypy check.py` returns:

```
check.py:5: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("List[Tuple[str, str]]" and "List[Tuple[str, List[Tuple[str, str]]]]")  [operator]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I know that this addition works though - I don't understand why it's "Unsupported", or what I should do to typehint this.

Comment: You're letting MyPy infer the types of those lists, and they're indeed incompatible. _"I know that this addition works"_ - it does, but it's not necessarily _type-safe_, there's plenty of valid Python code MyPy will quite deliberately disallow. If your expectation is just that they're e.g. `list[tuple[Any, Any]]`, include that.

Comment: I haven't worked with mypy, but I assume either the result (z) should be typehinted as allowing this addition or both x and y need to have the same typehint. `List[Tuple[str, Any]]` if you don't want too many Anys but think that union on str and inner list will be unreadable